# How to delete everything from Google Drive except "native" Google files like docs, sheets, presentations

Tags: google-drive

I'm migrating to a different cloud storage provider, and want to wipe all files that synced from my computer to Google Drive; however, I would like to keep all my Google Docs, spreadsheets, drawings, and presentations.

Is this possible to do easily?

Comment: What do you mean by "to do easily"? Are you open to third-party apps / chrome extensions / users scripts (Google Apps Scripts)?

Comment: By easily I mean anything quicker than going to the quota page to see which files take up most space and scroll down infinitely in order to select all. Yes I am open to third-party scripts.